# Dynamics 365 Authentication with OpenID provided by AWS Cognito Hosted UI

Tags: amazon-cognito, microsoft-dynamics

I'm having a bit of a strange issue where Dynamics 365 works fine using OpenID from AWS Cognito (our IDAM) if I use the hosted ui on the default out of the box domain but if I use a custom domain (e.g. authentication.companyx.com)

In both scenarios I can see the token going back to Dynamics in this format

code=YYY=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties=XXXZZZ

But one works and the other doesn't - any suggestions on where to start looking?

We also use cloudflare so authentication.companyx.com is routed through that

Have tried using an authority in dynamics of the custom domain and the out of the box one

Well known is the default AWS one based on the userpool  id